# PHP Injecting various dependencies into subcontrollers

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm building an intranet site with a frontcontroller that will pull the requested app's information from a repository and execute that subcontroller. The problem I have is each app can use different services with different configuration parameters and I need to get those services passed down to the subcontroller without smelling up the subcontroller's code with configuration stuff. Looking at the example below, I try using DI to pass things along which is ok for a couple services common to all the apps, but when I have many different services that are not common to all apps it becomes a constructor mess. Since the subcontrollers are created dynamically I can't simply pass just the dependencies needed for each individual controller.

I've debated storing the dependencies in the app repository and calling the sub controllers with the information pulled from that, but that still doesn't seem right to me. What's the proper way to do this without using a service locator or other anti-patterns?

```
$appRepository = new AppRepository('username_1', 'password_1', 'etc_1');
$userRepository = new UserRepository('username_2', 'password_2', 'etc_2');

// misc services used by apps
$barrinator = new Barrinator('bar_params');
$bazzinator = new Bazzinator('baz_params');

// example
$params['app_id'] = 'foo';
$params['user_id'] = 'bob';

$frontController = new FrontController($appRepository, $userRepository);
$frontController->execute($params);

class FrontController
{
    protected $appRepository = null;
    protected $userRepository = null;

    public function __construct(AppRepositoryInterface $appRepository, UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository)
    {
        $this->appRepository = $appRepository;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function execute($params)
    {
        $app = $this->appRepository->get($params['app_id']);
        $appController = $app->getControllerName();
        $controller = new $appController($this->userRepository);
        $controller->execute($params);
    }
}

abstract class AppAbstract
{
    protected $userRepository = null;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    abstract public function execute($params);
}

class Foo extends AppAbstract
{
    public function execute($params)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->get($params['user_id']);
        // etc.
    }
}

class Bar extends AppAbstract
{
    public function execute($params)
    {
        // halp! how to get barrinator resource
        $bar = $barrinator->get($params['bar_id']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use some help from a DI container.

The role of the container is build object graphs. I.e. the container can build your controllers and inject their dependencies automatically.

The front controller would then look like:

```
class FrontController
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function execute($params)
    {
        $app = $this->appRepository->get($params['app_id']);
        $appController = $app->getControllerName();
        $controller = $this->container->get($appController);
        $controller->execute($params);
    }
}
```

I'm biaised to suggest a container (I'm developing PHP-DI), but here is a list of containers: https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/6159681

Comment: So I basically need to have some configuration list somewhere of the subcontrollers and their dependencies and use another layer like a DIC to do the construction and injection?

Comment: @fwrawx Yes, though some containers use reflection to avoid having to write configuration. See here for example: http://php-di.org/doc/definition